# How to validate an Email in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, validation, email-validation

How can I validate the input value is a valid email address using php5. Now I am using this code

```
function isValidEmail($email){ 
     $pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"; 

     if (eregi($pattern, $email)){ 
        return true; 
     } 
     else { 
        return false; 
     }    
}
```

but it shows deprecated error. How can I fix this issue. Please help me.

Comment: The correct answer was already given, but regarding the *deprecated* issue: The usage of POSIX regular expressions (which `eregi` is a function of) is deprecated. Use [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) instead.

Comment: By the way, your regex is totally wrong. Some totally valid adresses will be marked as invalid by your function. Filtering email adresses with a regex is a nightmare.

Comment: You should use [RFC 822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822) standard and here is a good article [Parsing Email Adresses in PHP](http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email) that explains it.

Comment: Stay away from `regex` and `filter_var()` solutions for validating email. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42037557/953833

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You can use the `filter_var()` function, which gives you a lot of handy validation and sanitization options.

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

- [PHP Manual filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)
- Available in **PHP >= 5.2.0**

If you don't want to change your code that relied on your function, just do:

```
function isValidEmail($email){ 
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}
```

**Note**: For other uses (where you need Regex), the deprecated `ereg` function family (POSIX Regex Functions) should be replaced by the `preg` family ([PCRE Regex Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)). There are a small amount of differences, reading the Manual should suffice.

**Update 1**: As pointed out by [@binaryLV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php/5855853#comment6729146_5855853):

> PHP 5.3.3 and 5.2.14 had a [bug](http://bugs.php.net/52929) related to
>   FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, which resulted in segfault when validating
>   large values. Simple and safe workaround for this is using `strlen()`
>   before `filter_var()`. I'm not sure about 5.3.4 final, but it is
>   written that some 5.3.4-snapshot versions also were affected.

This bug has already been fixed.

**Update 2**: This method will of course validate `bazmega@kapa` as a valid email address, because in fact it is a valid email address. But most of the time on the Internet, you also want the email address to have a TLD: `bazmega@kapa.com`. As suggested in this [blog post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-validation-filter-var-updated/) (link posted by [@Istiaque Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php/5855853#comment18460128_5855853)), you can augment `filter_var()` with a regex that will check for the existence of a dot in the domain part (will not check for a *valid* TLD though):

```
function isValidEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) 
        && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email);
}
```

As [@Eliseo Ocampos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php/5855853#comment30608940_5855853) pointed out, this problem only exists before PHP 5.3, [in that version they changed the regex](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?r1=297250&r2=297350&pathrev=303779) and now it does this check, so you do not have to.

Comment: +1 That said, you might want to mention that this is only available in PHP 5.2.x and above. :-)

Comment: @middaparka: As the OP gets a deprecated message for `eregi`, it seems he is using PHP 5.3. But yes, it is important to mention it (for others)).

Comment: @middaparka Thanks, I added it. I left it out for the same reason what @Felix explained, but yes, others might be interested.

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 and 5.2.14 had a bug (http://bugs.php.net/52929) related to `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, which resulted in segfault when validating large values. Simple and safe workaround for this is using `strlen()` before `filter_val()`. I'm not sure about 5.3.4 final, but it is written that some 5.3.4-snapshot versions also were affected.

Comment: @binaryLV, `filter_val` or `filter_var` ?

Comment: @bažmegakapa, email address should be trimmed before the final testing, I think. The  validation  process in the answer does not check the presence of the dot in addres. `return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email);` - tests the presence of a dot in domain name part. An integer casting of the return value is also necessary.Found here:electrictoolbox.com/php-email-validation-filter-var-updated.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Useful resource, I will update my answer. But you have a misunderstanding: the return value of course does not have to be cast to an integer - the blogger only does this to make `echo` correctly display the boolean.

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed, probably 18 months old typo.

Comment: @kapa, Actually you don't need any more to check for a dot in the domain part. See http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?r1=297250&r2=297350&pathrev=303779

Comment: I would just like to note that this option backed up with a domain/MX record checkup you can be pretty sure the server also might really be able to process the emails you might send it.

Comment: You should return `filter_var(...) !== false` in your function to return a boolean ("`isValidEmail`" implies a boolean return value).

Comment: @stofl You are right, it also matches the OP's original signature better. Edited.

Comment: Sorry to dig out this post, but does this method also cover up SQL injection or similar methods?

Comment: @Norman This method covers email validation. It checks whether a string contains a valid email address. No database is mentioned, so it has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Comment: @kapa and at everyone: Sorry, my bad. I somehow thought that this method isn't working with htmlspecialchars. But the bug was somewhere else. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: This will validate:
 `$email = '"><script>alert(1);</script>"@test.com';
echo filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: @sergio Is it an invalid email address?

Comment: @kapa It can inject XSS, but filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  will validate it as an valid email, so need to be care

Comment: @sergio An email validator validates emails. That is its job. It should not care about XSS, SQL injection, etc. That is a different part of your application. When you output HTML, you should take precautions against XSS.

Comment: An important notice - in the last update, you changed the logic a bit since you removed the `!== false`.

Comment: this function won't work for emails with spanish characters like `Stéphane@yopmail.com`

Answer (score 9):

See the notes at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php:

> ```
> Note:
> ```
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, the regex extension is deprecated in favor of
>   the [PCRE extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php). Calling this
>   function will issue an E_DEPRECATED
>   notice. See [the list of differences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php)
>   for help on converting to PCRE.
>
> ```
> Note:
> ```
>
> [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), which uses a Perl-compatible regular expression
>   syntax, is often a faster alternative
>   to ereg().

Answer (score 7):

This is old post but I will share one my solution because noone mention here one problem before.

New email address can contain UTF-8 characters or special domain names like `.live`, `.news` etc.

Also I find that some email address can be on Cyrilic and on all cases standard regex or `filter_var()` will fail.

That's why I made an solution for it:

```
function valid_email($email) 
{
    if(is_array($email) || is_numeric($email) || is_bool($email) || is_float($email) || is_file($email) || is_dir($email) || is_int($email))
        return false;
    else
    {
        $email=trim(strtolower($email));
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)!==false) return $email;
        else
        {
            $pattern = '/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD';
            return (preg_match($pattern, $email) === 1) ? $email : false;
        }
    }
}
```

This function work perfectly for all cases and email formats.

Answer (score 3):

I always use this:

```
function validEmail($email){
    // First, we check that there's one @ symbol, and that the lengths are right
    if (!preg_match("/^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$/", $email)) {
        // Email invalid because wrong number of characters in one section, or wrong number of @ symbols.
        return false;
    }
    // Split it into sections to make life easier
    $email_array = explode("@", $email);
    $local_array = explode(".", $email_array[0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($local_array); $i++) {
        if (!preg_match("/^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$/", $local_array[$i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$/", $email_array[1])) { // Check if domain is IP. If not, it should be valid domain name
        $domain_array = explode(".", $email_array[1]);
        if (sizeof($domain_array) < 2) {
            return false; // Not enough parts to domain
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($domain_array); $i++) {
            if (!preg_match("/^(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])|([A-Za-z0-9]+))$/", $domain_array[$i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @unbreak I've tried your code and found that if you pass email as `alex@.` then it always returns true where it's not a valid email address.

Answer (score 3):

> User data is very important for a good developer, so don't ask again
>   and again for same data, use some logic to correct some basic error in data.

**Before validation of Email:** First you have to remove all illegal characters from email.

```
//This will Remove all illegal characters from email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

after that validate your email address using this `filter_var()` function.

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // To Validate the email
```

For e.g.

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";

// Remove all illegal characters from email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

// Validate email
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo $email." is a valid email address";
} else {
    echo $email." is not a valid email address";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- or "filter_var" from http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

```php
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

- or "EmailValidator" from https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator

```php
$validator = new EmailValidator();
$multipleValidations = new MultipleValidationWithAnd([
    new RFCValidation(),
    new DNSCheckValidation()
]);
$validator->isValid("example@example.com", $multipleValidations); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

take several care, a address as **iasd@x.z-----com** is INVALID, but filter_var() return true, many others strings (emails) INVALIDS return true using filter_var().

for validate email I use this function:

```
function correcorre($s){// correo correcto
    $x = '^([[:alnum:]](_|-|\.)*)*[[:alnum:]]+@([[:alnum:]]+(-|\.)+)*[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+$';
    preg_match("!$x!i", $s, $M);
    if(!empty($M[0]))return($M[0]);
    }
```

please improve and share, thanks