# PHP built in function to determine if email is valid

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate an Email in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php)

Does PHP have a built in function for determining if an email address is formatted properly. I know it can't go out and check if the email is actually active; I'm talking about just confirming that an email address is structurally correct.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) can do this:

```
$result = filter_var( 'bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
```

It returns `false` when it failed validation, and returns the e-mail address otherwise.

Comment: The validation process in the answer does not check the presence of the dot in addres. `return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\./', $email);` - tests the presence of a dot in domain name part. email address should be trimmed before the final testing, I think. An integer casting of the return value is also necessary.Found here:electrictoolbox.com/php-email-validation-filter-var-updated.

Comment: integer casting is necessary only for echoing purpose.

Comment: update 2018: this doesn't work for emails like `Stéphane@yopmail.com`..

Comment: @Coderanonymous You can add a second flag to make it work for unicode: `filter_var( 'Stéphane@yopmail.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_FLAG_EMAIL_UNICODE)`