# Error: Undefined Variable

Tags: php

Does anyone know how i can fix this error.

> Undefined variable: email in C:\wamp\www\Root\siginuppage.php on line 57

```
if (!preg_match(
        "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i"
        , $email
)) {
```

I am trying to set up an email verification form but this error occurs before any data is inputted. The undefined variable is email i can assume but how exactly do i define it??

```
$email = "$email"  along with $username="" and $password=""    perhaps  ?????
```

I am ridiculously new to this so a simple answer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't set `$email` anywhere. Set it.

Comment: http://php.net/variables

Comment: don't use regular expression for validating email, use [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: Some help on validating email in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php/5855853#5855853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, variables in php are represented by prefixing a `$` sign. So to define a variable `$email`, you need to do something like this,

```
 $email = "xyz@pqr.com"; //test email
```

Comment: "`$` is for variables"? What is that in reference to?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: tanx coder that helps a lot - just one more quick question does that definition mean that the email has to go in the format letters(any amount) @ letters(any amount) followed by .com(exact) ?

Comment: this might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address