# Email Validation Regex

Tags: php, regex

We have special requirements for our email verification. We want to allow the following:

- First and last characters must be alphanumeric.
- The middle section also allows alphanumeric + the following 3 special characters `.-_` (period, hyphen and underscore).
- Special characters cannot touch (2 periods cannot be next to eachother, or a hyphen underscore for instance).

So far I've managed to figure our how to check for alphanumeric: `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]`

But I'm completely stuck on the hardest part - the middle section. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you restricting the users ? Just send an email already. If you really want to validate then [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5855853). [This is also a good read](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you go down the path of email validation with regex, have you tried [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/filter_var) with [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)?

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)
{
    // Valid email.
}
```