# Email validation with validation on username to accept only letters, digits, underscore and DOT

Tags: php, regex

I know this question asked many times but I could not find any solution to my specific validation.

I want to validate a username in email address to accept only letters, digits, underscore and DOT and NO dash (-) or any special character such as !#%&*()

Like this: aaa@aa.com, d123@ad.com, 22_dd@dd.com, dfd.df@ds.com

NOT like this: ss-ee@sd.com, fsd!@asd.com, 11-ee@sd.com

what i did:

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+/", $email)) return("Invalid email address");
```

but it accepts dash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate an Email in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?!.*?\.\.)[\w.]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$/', $email)) 
    return("Invalid email address");
```

Comment: can i prevent double dot sequentially. like this dd..dd@ad.com

Comment: This will match `myemailª@test.com`

Comment: @anubhava you're right, regexbuddy was giving me a false positive. sry about that.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent 2 consecutive dots (`.`) use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*?\.\.)`

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9_.]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+$/im', $email))
    return("Invalid email address");
```

EXPLANATION:

```
^             # Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed)
(?!           # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   .             # Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)
      *?            # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   \.            # Match the character “.” literally
   \.            # Match the character “.” literally
)
[a-z0-9_.]    # Match a single character present in the list below
                 # A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive)
                 # A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                 # A single character from the list “_.”
   +             # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
@             # Match the character “@” literally
[A-Z0-9.-]    # Match a single character present in the list below
                 # A character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive)
                 # A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                 # The literal character “.”
                 # The literal character “-”
   +             # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.            # Match the character “.” literally
[A-Z]         # Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive)
   +             # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\$             # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex that will also prevent 2 consecutive dots in the username:

```
^(?!.*\.\..*@)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@\S+\.[a-zA-Z]+$
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fQ7yQ0/11).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\.\..*@)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are two consecutive dots in the username part only
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+` - one or more ASCII letters, digits or `_` or `.`
- `@` - a `@`
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

*Sample code*:

```
$re = "/^(?!.*\\.\\..*@)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@\\S+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$/m"; 
$str = "334345jtjert..j547j@ds.com\n334345jtjert.j547j@ds.com\nss-ee@sd.com\nfsd!@asd.com\n11-ee@sd.com"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: got: Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in

Comment: Please check now, I included the "@..." part to the regex.

Comment: Please check my last regex version: the regex will prevent user from entering consecutive dots in the username, the TLD is matched using your own pattern.

Comment: @AymanHussein Please check my update, and note that anubhava's solution also fails the match if there are two consecutive dots in the domain part.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
[\\w\\-\\+\\&\\*]+(?:\\.[\\w\\-\\_\\+\\&\\*]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}
```